The appUrlOpen event is not being triggered when the URL is opened in IONIC
I’m trying to handle redirect URLs from an external service (a Laravel backend) into my Ionic app, but I’m running into issues.
Context:
External URL Example: https://my-laravel-website.com/api/get-tap?tap_id=23
Goal:
When the URL is opened, I want my Ionic app to handle it, extract the necessary information, and close any open browser windows.
My Code:
AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.tebk.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="my-laravel-website.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>


Info.plist:
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>https</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>my-laravel-website.com</string>
</dict>
</array>

my-component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';
constructor() {
  this.initializeApp();
}
initializeApp() {
  App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
    console.log('App opened with URL:', data.url);
  });
}

strings.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">براعم النخبة الأهلية</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">براعم النخبة الأهلية</string>
    <string name="package_name">com.tebk.app</string>
    <string name="custom_url_scheme">com.tebk.app</string>
</resources>

build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    namespace "com.tebk.app"
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tebk.app"
         ...
     }

Issue:
The appUrlOpen event is not being triggered when the URL is opened
I am testing the app with Android Studio on my real device
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Try waiting for platform ready:
initializeApp() { this.platform.ready().then(async () => {    App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {     console.log('App opened with URL:', data.url);   }); })
}

it is not working, also I generated apk file and installed it on my device instead of running it in Android Studio, same result @NajamUsSaqib

did you follow this guide? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

Yes, I read the docs, created a site associative file, and verified it using Google's Asset Links tool, it is configured correctly. But when I use the App Links Tool in Android Studio it failed the errors are (the DAL file did not contain your package name,  and your app's fingerprint) I checked them, and they are the same in the app and assetlinks.json @Skin_phil

In Android Studio: Build -> Generate Signed App Bundle/APK
Then I installed the release APK on my phone and worked.
